# Rocket League Split Screen Online PC

Tags: pc, rocket-league

I was reading that rocket league has split screen online with guest accounts for PS4. I was just wondering if the same was true for PC? Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, it is.**

However, it seems pretty unstable right now.

Comment: That's great / a shame. Thanks for the info

Comment: They are working on it, I think it is a matter of weeks at worst.